# jpopupmenu menuitem actionperformed not triggered

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

The popupmenu and menuitem show up fine, but I can't find out why When I click on the menuitem, nothing happen, not even a simple println.
what am I missing?

here's my code :

```
private void jLabel33MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        Component source = (Component) evt.getSource();
        Component panelSource = source.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt)){

            ModelLigneModifier ligne = (ModelLigneModifier) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(ModelLigneModifier.class, (Component) evt.getSource());
            ligne.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0), 4));
            JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
            JMenuItem modifier = new JMenuItem("Modifier le prix");
            modifier.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Controleur.supprimerLigne(panelSource, ligneCompte);
                    System.out.println("modifier");
                }
            });
            JMenuItem supprimer = new JMenuItem("Supprimer la ligne");
            supprimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Controleur.modifierLigne(panelSource, ligneCompte);
                    System.out.println("modifier");
                }
            });
            menu.add(new JMenuItem("Modifier le prix"));
            menu.add(new JMenuItem("Supprimer la ligne"));
            //ligne.setComponentPopupMenu(menu);
            menu.show(ligne, evt.getX(), evt.getY());

        }
        else{
        Controleur.ajouterLigneCompte(panelSource);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Probably to late to use `ligne.setComponentPopupMenu(menu);` if you're using a `MouseListener` to trigger the popup

Comment: Why are you adding menuItems to menu in runtime? That is maybe a problem. Try to add menu and menuItems to container in init metods of class.

Comment: @mstfyldz Creating popup menus dynamically is quite a common task (changing them based on specific context).  Don't think I'd be using `setComponentPopupMenu` though, probably would use `show` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't really understand your first comment.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I replace setComponentPopMenu by show but it still doesn't go to actionperformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click on the menuitem, nothing happen, not even a simple println.

You create a JMenuItem and add an ActionListener to it, which is correct:

```
JMenuItem modifier = new JMenuItem("Modifier le prix");
modifier.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Controleur.supprimerLigne(panelSource, ligneCompte);
        System.out.println("modifier");
    }
});
```

But then you add a new menu item without an ActionListener to the popup menu, which is incorrect:

```
menu.add(new JMenuItem("Modifier le prix"));
```

The code should be:

```
//menu.add(new JMenuItem("Modifier le prix"));
menu.add( modifier );
```

Comment: I am so dumb sometimes...Thanks a lot !